# Razorpay .net integration automatic payment capture

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway, razorpay

I am trying to integrate razorpay payment gateway into my application and while doing the same , I came across the concept of automatic payment capture. In the razorpay documentation for setting automatic and manual expiry period they are using **payment.capture_options**. But I am not sure how they got the payment object. Please help

reference URL
https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payments/capture-settings/api/

[image]
code from documentation.
How do I get this payment object while creating an order. ?